# How to parse json arrary?

Tags: json, jackson, spring-boot

I have come across a problem of parsing json data . I am building project using spring boot based on REST api . When i have to parse data corresponding to domain then it is very easy , i use RequestBody in controller method with domain name but in current scenerio i have a list of domain in json form :

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "type":"abc",
         "subtypes":[
            {
               "leftValue":"BEACH",
               "rightValue":"MOUNTAIN",
               "preferencePoint":60
            },
            {
               "leftValue":"ADVENTURE",
               "rightValue":"LEISURE",
               "preferencePoint":60
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"mno",
         "subtypes":[
            {
               "leftValue":"LUXURY",
               "rightValue":"FUNCTIONAL",
               "preferencePoint":60
            },
            {
               "leftValue":"SENSIBLE",
               "rightValue":"AGGRESIVE",
               "preferencePoint":0
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I am sending data in list where `type` is the property of class `Type`
and class Type has list of `Subtypes` class and subtype class contains `leftValue` and `rightValue` as `enums`

I am using spring boot which uses jackson liberary by default and i want to parse this data into corresponding `Type` class using `Jackson`. Can any one provide me solution.

Comment: google it, add what error you get

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear to me if you have static or dynamic payload.

**Static payload**

For static one, I would personally try to simplify your payload structure. But your structure would look like this. (I skipped getters and setters. You can generate them via [Lombok library](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html)).

```
public class Subtype{
  private String leftValue;
  private String rightValue;
  private int preferencePoint;
}

public class Type{
  private String type;
  private List<Subtype> subtypes;
}

public class Data{
  private List<Type> data;
}
```

Then in your controller you inject `Data` type as `@RequestBody`.

**Dynamic payload**

For dynamic payload, there is option to inject `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>` as `@RequestBody`. Where value in that map is of type `Object`, which can be casted into another `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>` and therefore this approach support also nested objects. This can support infinite nesting this way. The only downside is that you need to cast `Object`s into correct types based on key from the map.

BTW, with pure Spring or Spring Boot I was always able to avoid explicit call against Jackson API, therefore I don't recommend to go down that path.

Comment: thanks for replying @ikrnac In Subtype class leftValue and rightValue is enum you can say SubtypEnums. how can i parse this dynamic payload?